# How to fill an element with a color with only javascript? (not changing the background color, but fill color on top of the whole element)

Tags: javascript, colors

I am totally new to coding and I was forced to do a coding project at school and I feel hopeless.

This is a piece of code I got:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string ");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Which if you go to Youtube homepage and paste it on your developer console in your browser, it changes the background color of channel names to blue.

But this is not I want.

I want the color filling on top of the channel names. So the you should only see blue rectangles but not the channel names.

I also want to add text on the blue rectangles, and best be able to control the opacity of the blue rectangles.

Since I am not building the website, I reckon I can only use javascript on the developer console but not CSS to do the job.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: 1) Filling an elemnt with a color is done by changing its background. I am not sure sure I understand what you are asking. 2) Don't feel limited to the developer console, you can write an html doc, a css file, and a js file in your local drive and open the html in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string ");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";  

  x[i].innerText="Something"; /* You can replace text what you want to see*/
  x[i].style.opacity = '0.5'; /* Also you can change opacity */ 
  x[i].style.color = "red"; /* You can change text color */
}
```

Try to change text color.

Answer (score 0):

You can change anything, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const element = [document.getElementById("youtuber-name-box"),
                 document.getElementById("youtuber-name")];
                 /* Accessing to this styles */
element[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue"; // Bg color
var padding = 1;
function r(){
if(padding < 80) {padding += 1; element[0].setAttribute("style","padding:"+padding+"px");
setTimeout(()=>{r();},50);
}
if(padding === 79){ // last
  element[1].style.fontSize = "35px";
  element[1].style.fontFamily = "monospace";
  element[1].style.color = "black";
}
}
r();

});
```

```css
#youtuber-name-box {
background-color: gray; display:table; padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="youtuber-name-box">

<i id="youtuber-name">Meth</i>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Young Kyun Jin's answer is the closest to what I want, by changing the text color  to transparent.

But it's still not quite what I want. Because I cannot add new text in the blue rectangle. The new text will be transparent as well.

[I made a picture to explain better. I want the to add color on top of an existing element, which I can add text on the color and, if possible, change the opacity of the color so I can still see what is under it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UAcd.png)tps://i.stack.imgur.com/5XoOK.png

I think I can't do it by simply change text to transparent because I can't hide the image by changing it to transparent.

I guess I might somehow create a new element and somehow place it exactly on top of the existing one. I got a piece of code which kinda does that but not quite:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string ");
var i;

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); //Create a canvas element
//Set canvas width/height
canvas.style.width='100%';
canvas.style.height='100%';
//Set canvas drawing area width/height
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//Position canvas
canvas.style.position='absolute';
canvas.style.left=0;
canvas.style.top=0;
canvas.style.zIndex=100000;
canvas.style.pointerEvents='none'; //Make sure you can click 'through' the     canvas
document.body.appendChild(canvas); //Append canvas to body element
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    context.rect(x[i].getBoundingClientRect().left+scrollX , x[i].getBoundingClientRect().top+scrollY , x[i].getBoundingClientRect().width, x[i].getBoundingClientRect().height);
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.fill();
}
```

But then the rectangle created by this is not quite right.

1. It is not exactly placed on top of the elements. It just scrolls with the canvas. So even if the element don't move when you scroll, the rectangles still scroll.
2. For some reason the rectangle is not correctly placed at the first place. (I am using Chrome developer console)
3. The canvas is the size of view port but not the size of whole document. Rectangles are not drawn out of the canvas.

Which is why I don't want create new element and place is on top of existing element. It causes too many problems and simply just don't work.

Is there something I can change/add in the style (just like changing the background color) to fill the element with color on top of everything existed in the element?

Once again, I am not the builder of the website, I am just creating some sort of plugin to the website so I reckon I can only use javascript but not css or html. Or if there is a way to do so please tell me.